# CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane

Tags: c#, java, ios

How can I replicate the functionality of CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane in other languages as java, c# or c++?

Comment: The answer depends on what data structure your using for the image buffer / bitmap. Are you thinking of a specific operating system, windowing system or UI toolkit?

Comment: I am trying to get the planes of a buffer containing YUV image data. I need to get 2 planes, the Y and the UV. Once I can get these places I will feed them into OpenGL in the next manner: glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, bufferWidth, bufferHeight, 
             0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
             yBuffer);

Comment: YUV image data can be stored in many different ways. You'll need to provide more information about the specific image data in your case. Do you have it as a byte array? Or is there a more specific data structure involved? Is this all on iOS (the keyword "Java" indicates otherwise)?

Comment: Yes the image is received as a simple byte array holding the information in yuv420sp format. I know for iOS we can use CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane to get the Y and the UV planes, but no idea of how to do it in java, c# or c++. I am trying really to write the functionality of this function in Java, but so fat no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YUV420SP format consists of two planes. The first plane contains the luminance information (Y values) and the second one contains the chrominance values (U and V values). Futhermore, there is a Y value for each pixel but just a U and a V value for each 2 by 2 pixel block. Finally, the U and V values are interleaved in the second plane.

So your byte array is most likely organized like this (each byte contains either a Y, U or V value):

```
YYYYY ... YYYYUVUV ... UVUV
```

Let's assume the image is 400 by 300 pixels. Then you have 120,000 Y values followed by 30,000 U/V pairs.

Since you're using Java and Java doesn't have pointers that can point into the middle of an array, you will need to use array indices instead of addresses. So a more or less equivalent implementation of `CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane` could look like this:

```
int GetBaseIndexOfPlane(int plane, int imageWidth, int imageHeight)
{
    if (plane == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return imageWidth * imageHeight;
}
```

Most likely, your image data doesn't contain any information about the size of the image. So you'll have to get that information from somewhere else and provide it to the method. On the other hand, you don't need to provide the byte array to the method. It's not required to compute the offset of any of the planes.

Comment: Ooops my answer was to long so I put it as an auto-answer

Answer (score 0):

Excellent! But as you say Java has no pointers so I cannot pass the plane to OpenGL:

```
// Y plane
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, bufferWidth, bufferHeight, 0, GL_LUMINANCE,
GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(frame, 0));

// UV Plane
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, bufferWidth / 2, bufferHeight / 2, 0, 
GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(frame, 1));
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but, would it be correct your code to get the start/end of the planes, and then create 2 new buffers (Y & UV)? in iOS I can pass the pointers, but in Java i cannot see another way than re-create 2 buffers.

Comment: Yes, you most likely need to copy the Y and UV data into two separate buffers. (I'm not really proficient in using OpenGL in Java.)

Comment: Thanks anyway for your answer, was really helpful